# Ricci flat metric on $n$-sphere?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Can you put a Ricci flat metric on the $n$-sphere, $n>4$?

Comment: I am have not been following the subject recently, but I think, the existence of a Ricci flat $n$-sphere is an open problem for $>3$. I think any such metric will necessarily have generic holonomy, and no examples of compact simply-connected Ricci-flat manifolds generic holonomy are known. See references in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/16818/are-there-ricci-flat-riemannian-manifolds-with-generic-holonomy
and especially Berger's "Panaramic view of Riemannian geometry".

Comment: It seems that such metric does not admit an isometric $S^1$-action.
I.e. the metric if exists has almost no symmetry. Therefore it is unlikely that one can construct it.

Comment: Anton, your logic is unclear to me. I cannot think of any Ricci-flat simply-connected closed manifolds with a circle action (e.g. the ones with holonomy in $SU(2m)$, $Sp(m)$, or $Spin(7)$ are spin and have positive $A$-hat-genus so no circle action there; I am less sure what happens for $G_2$ holonomy). Nor do I see why a Ricci flat sphere necessarily must have a finite isometry group.

Comment: @Igor, you right, there is no logic, but no $S^1$-action either :)

Comment: Compact $G_2$ manifolds also have finite symmetry groups, by the same argument as for the other holonomy groups: a vector field preserving the Riemannian metric would have to be dual to a harmonic 1-form. By Bochner, a harmonic 1-form must be parallel, and so the holonomy reduces, by deRham splitting theorem, to a product of holonomy groups, and the manifold is, up to finite covering, a product with a product metric.

Comment: It is worthwhile to note that there can be no Killing vector fields for such a metric, because that would imply the existence of a non-trivial harmonic one-form. 

Comment: @Igor: In fact, the holonomy of any metric on the $n$-sphere is $SO(n)$, not just the Ricci-flat ones; i.e., the $n$-sphere does not admit any metric of reduced holonomy.